# Display all the object values in a label (WFA)

Tags: c#, list, object

I would like to know how I can properly display all the objects inside a list on a label.

```
{
class HighScore
{
    public string name;
    public int points;

    public HighScore(string N, int P)
    {
        this.name = N;
        this.points = P;
    }


}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<HighScore> score = new List<HighScore>();
        score.Add(new HighScore("Paul", 20));
        score.Add(new HighScore("Robert", 30));
        score.Add(new HighScore("John", 25));
        score.Add(new HighScore("Michael", 300));

        foreach(HighScore per in score)
        {
            label1.Text = per.name + "  " + per.points;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried using a foreach loop to make the label display all the values from the list, but it only displayed one value, and not all of them. How can I properly display this list on a label?

Comment: use `+=` instead, also you can use `string.Join` method

Comment: Where do I use the string.Join method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you use `=`, so on each iteration you replace `label1.Text` value.
As solution you can simple use `+=` operator, so in will be append to `label1.Text` value.

Yet another way: [override *ToString*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173154(v=vs.80).aspx) method in your class, like

```
public override string ToString(){
    return per.name + "  " + per.points;
}
```

and use it `label1.Text += per.ToString();`
or with [`string.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/dd992421(v=vs.110).aspx) like

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<HighScore> score = new List<HighScore>();
    score.Add(new HighScore("Paul", 20));
    score.Add(new HighScore("Robert", 30));
    score.Add(new HighScore("John", 25));
    score.Add(new HighScore("Michael", 300));

    label1.Text = string.Join(",", score);
}
```

if you can't override `ToString` you can use next linq [*Select*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb548891(v=vs.110).aspx) like

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<HighScore> score = new List<HighScore>();
    score.Add(new HighScore("Paul", 20));
    score.Add(new HighScore("Robert", 30));
    score.Add(new HighScore("John", 25));
    score.Add(new HighScore("Michael", 300));

    label1.Text = string.Join(",", score.Select(per=>per.name + "  " + per.points));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution should be "reformulated" like this:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<HighScore> score = new List<HighScore>();
            score.Add(new HighScore("Paul", 20));
            score.Add(new HighScore("Robert", 30));
            score.Add(new HighScore("John", 25));
            score.Add(new HighScore("Michael", 300));
            StringBuilder labelResult = new StringBuilder();
            foreach(HighScore per in score)
            {
                labelResult.Apend(per.name + "  " + per.points+"\n");
            }
            labe1.Text = labelResult.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: If you like, I can explain you a better solution,

Comment: No thanks, both you and user Grundy provided me with plenty of good information on how to tackle this problem. Thanks for educating me!